# Angular 9 mat-select dynamic content only displays correctly when I click on the mat-select component

Tags: angular

I am building a component that uses mat-select with dynamic (previous selection) data that I get from the backend. The dynamic data only shows when I trigger the change event by clicking on the mat-select component. But it should load with the previously saved selection loaded.

Is there a way for me to trigger the change event programmatically once the data loads so that the component has shows my previous selection from the database?

```
<mat-select [formControl]="selected" (selectionChange)="selectedItems($event.value)" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of objArray" [value]="obj.title">{{obj.title}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Component Structure

- Parent -> gets data from API

  - Child -> passes items and checked items

    - mat-select -> uses @Input items and @Input checked_items

The FormControl uses FormControl(checked_items) to check the items saved in the database

this is the component before it is clicked.

[image]

this is the component after it is clicked.

[image]

[image]

I want the data loaded into the component before it is clicked displaying the selection from the database.

Comment: Are you using API?

Comment: You should not have to do that. Maybe you are updating the array instead of replacing it ? Which would eventually prevent the change detector to detect the change ? If you still want to trigger the detection manually, you can inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `changeDetector.detectChanges()` but having to do that is sometimes the sign of a design flaw.

Comment: Can you show the code where you update `objArray` ?

Comment: @Linker I am using an api and get the data returned via a service. If I click on the component then the dynamic data displays because it is picked up in ngOnChanges and ngDoCheck and other lifecycle hooks so data is coming in from the api but only after the component is instantiated.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle can this change be called in the parent and picked up in the child?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle ChangeDetectorRef worked perfectly called in parent, lekker!